# Jenkins: push repo branch 'staging' to staging server, and branch 'production' to production server

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm a Jenkins nooooobie. Is it possible / painless combine these two yaml files and place in one repo such that when I push to branch 'staging' Jenkins pushes it to the staging server and when I push to branch 'production' Jenkins pushes to the production server?

**STAGING**

```
jenkins:
  project: "Docker Slot StageSlot1 (WestUS)"
  certbot_url: "https://cert.bots.company.com/"
  certbot_token: "company-certbot-token"
  domain_file: domain.yaml
docker:
  ucp: "tcp://ucp-companydocker.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:443"
  dtr: dtr-companydocker.westus.cloudapp.azure.com
  ucpid: companyucpdockerwestus
  dtrid: jenkinscompanydtrwestus
  stackname: COMPANY-SS1-Staging
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.build.tmpl
  compose: docker-compose-ss1
  dtrtag: "/company/stagslot"
  ext_port: 8310
  ext_https_port: 8311
  build_cmd: ""
  label: "/Staging/COMPANY/SS1"
  cnt: 2
  dir_rand: PM25SS1
  siteurl: "http://company-ss1-stage.trafficmanager.net"
  build_cache: false
slack:
  channel: "#webops"
  log_errors: false
git:
  gitid: company-ss1-id
  giturl: "git@github.com:company/company-SS1.git"
  gitbranch: staging
```

**PRODUCTION**

```
jenkins:
  project: "Docker Slot ProdSlot1"
  certbot_url: "https://cert.bots.company.com/"
  certbot_token: "company-certbot-token"
  domain_file: domain.yaml
docker:
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.build.tmpl
  build_cmd: ""
  cnt: 4
  dir_rand: PM25MS1
  siteurl: "http://company-prodslot1.us-west1.gce.companyp.cloud"
  build_cache: false
k8s:
  gcpid: 'gcp-web-platform'
  namespace: 'production'
  site: 'ms-01'
  env: 'prod'
  clusters:
    - name: 'gke-web-1'
      region: 'us-west1'
      slothost: 'company-ms01.us-west1.gce.companyp.cloud'
    - name: 'gke-web-2'
      region: 'us-central1'
      slothost: 'company-ms01.us-central1.gce.companyp.cloud'
slack:
  channel: "#webops"
  log_errors: false
git:
  gitid: company-prodslot1-id
  giturl: "git@github.com:company/company-prodslot1.git"
  gitbranch: production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to automating with Jenkins! :D

Jenkins provides environment variables that you can use to supplement the logic in your jobs. In this case, you might be interested in the `GIT_BRANCH` and `GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH` env variables.

```
GIT_BRANCH - The remote branch name, if any.
GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH - The local branch name being checked out, if applicable.
```

So in your job, you can do something like (bash inspired pseudo code follows!!!):

```
case ${GIT_BRANCH} in
    staging) push_to_staging_sever;;
    production) push_to_production_sever;;
esac
```

There are also multi-branch job approaches to working with different branches, but this is a good introductory approach to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Let us know how it works out!

Comment: To see the other env vars that Jenkins injects into your job, take a look at `env-vars.html/` on your server.  For example, on localhost you would go to http://localhost:8080/env-vars.html/.